# Why the UIView extension doesn't work using combine?

Tags: uikit, gesture, combine, publisher, subscriber

My Problem :

When I use UIView extension about Combine, It doesn't work.
But use TabGesture extension, it works.
I don`t know why..

UIGestureRecognizer file
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I do this, the publisher doesn't work.
But, If I do this(change tabPublisher -> tapPublisher()), the code works.
I don't know why..!
[image]

Comment: Don't add your code samples into Stack Overflow as pictures.  The system lets you [include the code as text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help).